# Calculating quantiles for whole dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantile

I have dataframe in jupyter notebook (pandas) where mean, standard deviation, description etc. works properly.

When I tried to calculate `quantiles` with this code (arguments are from [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)):

```
path = r'p_80'
frame = ioi_frame(path) #gives me dataframe

q1 = frame.quantile(0.25, method="table")
q1
```

[That is dataframe I put in code]

[image: 2]

I get output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12792/1566283168.py in <module>
      2 frame = ioi_frame(path)
      3 
----> 4 q1 = frame.quantile(0.25, method="table")
      5 q1

TypeError: quantile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

Let me know, why `method` is not working and how could I calculate quantiles for the whole dataframe?

Comment: what does`ioi_frame()` do? i don't think it returns a pandas dataframe , is it? what does `print(type(frame))` return?

Comment: Basically concatenate dataframes:


`def ioi_frame(path):

    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "*.csv"))

    li = []

    for filename in all_files:
        
    df = ioi_lim_alone(filename)
        
         li.append(df)

    
    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
    
    return frame`

Comment: I got this:
`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: What version of pandas?

Comment: Pandas version: 1.4.1

Comment: I updated pandas, but now I still don't get one Q1 for whole dataframe:

`ioi-p_80\ab3b80    0.000000
ioi-p_80\bg3a80         NaN
ioi-p_80\bi3b80    0.210938
Name: 0.25, dtype: float64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pandas docs you linked for the method parameter

```
 When ‘table’, the only allowed interpolation methods are ‘nearest’, ‘lower’, and ‘higher’.
```

As an interpolation was not specified it uses the default `linear`

Try using one of the allowed interpolation parameters and see if that works.